# Dojo Tabs - Populating w/ HTML/JS & Anchor links

Tags: hyperlink, tabs, dojo, tabcontainer

I'm developing a web application that is making use of tabs. I've run one issue that seems small, but I haven't been able to locate a solution and I'm worried it is indicative of larger problems with my code.

My application has one main page that includes a tab container with several content panes then inserted as children. I figured that having each content pane load an external HTML file and loading it that way was a good solution - it seemed to provide modular design and allow for easy changing of the contents of an individual tab. The issue I am running into now is that while everything loads correctly, I'm unable to provide anchor links in inside a tab or between tabs. Here is some sample code:

```
var tabs = new TabContainer({
    style: "height: 100%; width: 100%;" 
}, "tab-container");
tabs.startup();
var metadata = new ContentPane({
    title: "Metadata",
    id: "Metadata"
});
/* repeat for the non-metadata content panes */
request.get("/js/viewer/templates/splash.html").then(function (results) {
    splash.set("content", results);
});
/* repeat for each pane */
```

For my metadata page I want it to contain information about the datasets I am providing to users. Ideally, it would have a table of contents with anchor links to the proper entries. However, when I implement an anchor link, like so:

```
<a href="#test">Click me to jump down the page!</a>
<!-- some content here -->
<div id="test">We made it!</div>
```

The link is clickable and it does in fact bring you to the proper location, but it seems to invariably load this in a new frame that requires a user to reload the page if they wish to do anything else. I've tried playing with  tag properties but it's been to no avail. I'm also hoping to be able to link between tabs (say, if a user is querying on one of the query pages I have presented them and then wants to know where a dataset came from or other information).

Here is a simple imgur album showing what happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1HgA.jpg

After clicking the link in the first image, you're sent down the page. However, the tab bar and the navigation bar of the page disappear completely, even when you scroll back up. I don't know why this is.

So, this has been a long question, but here is the core of it:

**What am I doing wrong with anchor links?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, this behavior seems to be caused by interaction of the `overflow: hidden` CSS property of my website's body interacting with the `height: 100%` property of my tab container. I didn't realize that the `overflow: hidden` property was set because it was part of a framework I was using. By changing the overflow property I have been able to achieve the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question:

You should put all JavaScript inside your main page, not inside partials. This is not considered a best practice with JavaScript because it means you will have to `eval()` the content and usually when you start doing that when you don't need to, then you're doing something wrong.

In this case you can easily add all JavaScript code to the main page. If you need to wait for a specific tab to be opened or loaded, you can use the `onShow` or `onLoad` events on the `dijit/layout/ContentPane` widgets.

---

Also, when you're using `ContentPane` you should use the proper setters for adding content/HTML to it.

Rather than doing:

```
request.get("/js/viewer/templates/splash.html").then(function (results) {
     dojo.byId("Splash").innerHTML = results;
});
```

You should be doing:

```
request.get("/js/viewer/templates/splash.html").then(function (results) {
    splash.set("content", results);
});
```

Or if you don't have a reference anymore to the `splash` variable, you should be using `registry.byId("splash").set("content", results)`.

---

About the hyperlinks, I have no idea. I'm not getting the same behavior, so could you explain a bit further on that?

Here's a (as far as I can see) working example: http://jsfiddle.net/n4515tsz/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I checked out your JSfiddle and that is exactly what I'm *trying* to do, but it doesn't seem to be happening. I made a simple imgur album which I'm editing into my question to try and illustrate what exactly is happening. I've made the other changes you suggested, though (and thanks for the suggestion about just using onLoad... totally slipped my mind!) Much appreciated

Comment: Could it be that you have `target="_blank"` on those links or so?

Comment: They don't. I tried adding `target="_blank"` and they did open in a new browser tab (which is different from the problem I'm seeing - they hijack the current browser tab). Forcing `target="_self"` didn't solve the issue, though. The code second code block I posted is the exact code I'm using, with the exception of some removed Lorem Ipsum to fill space. I wish I had the rep to +1 you on this site as you've already earned it.